# Transition from tab in actionbar to full screen window in android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I have the following problem. I have an actionbar (I use the sherlockactionbar) with 3 tabs, which each display a fragment when clicked on. In one of the fragments I have a list. What I want to do is that if an element of the list is clicked on a new full screen view **without** tabs slides in from right to left. It shall look like in whatsapp when you click on a chat and the chat is displayed.

I tried to implement it by defining a fragment for the chat and using a fragment transaction. But what happens is that the chat fragment slides in but the actionbar remains. It looks like the tab fragment is replaced.

So my question is the following: Do I have the right approach by using a fragment to implement the chat view. Or should I use a new activity for the chat?

I'm a beginner in java and android so I don't know if this question makes any sense or if I am missing an important point.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in this case i'm not able to judge the right way, but i know that you can use a fragment or activity for this scope. It's your choice.
In your case the problem with the fragment is that the actionbar is releated to the father activity and not to the child fragment.
If you want to hide it you must do something similar( in the fragment ):

```
getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
```

But in this way the other fragment lose the action bar, because the fragment are four but the action bar only one.
In this case in every fragment you must control the action bar visibility and use:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().show();
```

If you want to show it.

If you use a new activity, the new activity have a new action bar, and you can work on it to hide or ski it different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have managed a way to get the desired layout: I used a FragmentActivity that displays fragments and that defines a method to add and display new fragments (addFragment). For the Fragments (frag a, b, and c) that I wanted to display in three tabs I defined a new "mother-fragment" with a tabhost. This tabhost loads the three fragments. To get the slide out where the whole tabhost gets replaced by a new layout I call the addFragment-method from the onItemClick-method in the fragment a.

Comment: I think that you've find the most scalable solution. Good luck!